# How to train a tensorflow.js model using a csv file?

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

Is it possible to train a tensorflow.js model using the path to a csv file on my computer? thank you!

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 8):

From the version **0.14.1**, You can read csv file using [tf.data.csv](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#data.csv). However the data should be sent by a server.

One can serve a local file using a server like [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server).

```
http-server -c1 --cors .
```

Or using python3 http-server

```
python3 -m http.server .
```

Then you can read your csv file

```
const csvUrl = 'localhost:port/file'; 

async function run() {

   const csvDataset = tf.data.csv(
     csvUrl, {
       columnConfigs: {
         medv: {
           isLabel: true
         }
       }
     });

// then you can use your dataset

}
```

Comment: Our `tf.data.csv()` convenience method does indeed assume a URL source; it just does `return new CSVDataset(new URLDataSource(source), csvConfig);`.  Using the slightly lower-level API, you can use `FileDataSource` there instead, passing it files from a browser upload (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53639919/load-tensorflow-js-model-from-local-file-system-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

You can start here: https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.14.1/#data.csv .
Not sure if you can pull the csv from the local file storage though. But what have you tried?

Come back when you have some work done!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert the data into a JSON file with an online converter. It may be the easiest way.