# Load Tensorflow js model from local file system in javascript

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I have converted a keras model to tensorflow json format and saved it locally in my computer. I am trying to load that json model in a javascript code using the below command

```
model = await tf.loadModel('web_model')
```

But the model is not getting loaded.
Is there a way to load tensorflow json model from local file system?

Comment: I guess you are not serving from a dev server? Using your browser to just open the html file will result in problems in the xhr requests used to fetch the file. Maybe try out https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

Comment: I have just started exploring tensorflow js and using my brower to test things

Answer (score 43):

I know you're trying to load your model in a browser but if anybody lands here that's trying to do it in Node, here's how:

```
const tf = require("@tensorflow/tfjs");
const tfn = require("@tensorflow/tfjs-node");
const handler = tfn.io.fileSystem("./path/to/your/model.json");
const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(handler);
```

Comment: This is fantastic. Thank you.

Comment: `const tf = require("@tensorflow/tfjs-node");
const handler = tf.io.fileSystem("./path/to/your/model.json");
const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(handler);`

Import of tfjs is not required if you import tfjs-node

Answer (score 14):

`LoadModel` uses `fetch` under the hood. And fetch cannot access the local files directly. It is meant to be used to get files served by a server. More on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50007055/fetch-request-to-local-file-not-working).
To load a local file with the browser, there is two approaches, asking the user to upload the file with

```
<input type="file"/>
```

Or serving the file by a server.

In these two scenarios, `tf.js` provides way to load the model.

1. Load the model by asking the user to upload the file

**html**

```
<input type="file" id="upload-json"/>
<input type="file" id="upload-weights"/>
```

**js**

```
const uploadJSONInput = document.getElementById('upload-json');
const uploadWeightsInput = document.getElementById('upload-weights');
const model = await tfl.loadModel(tf.io.browserFiles(
 [uploadJSONInput.files[0], uploadWeightsInput.files[0]]));
```

2. Serving the local files using a server

To do so, one can use the following npm module [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) to serve the directory containing both the weight and the model. It can be installed with the following command:

```
 npm install http-server -g
```

Inside the directory, one can run the following command to launch the server:

```
http-server -c1 --cors .
```

Now the model can be loaded:

```
 // load model in js script
 (async () => {
   ...
   const model = await tf.loadFrozenModel('http://localhost:8080/model.pb', 'http://localhost:8080/weights.json')
 })()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. But I am getting the below error while trying to load the files in model
    Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsText' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.

Comment: Maybe, you have to read the file after it has been loaded using an event listener

Comment: using the http server worked for me

Answer (score 4):

If you're using React with `create-react-app`, you can keep your saved model files in your [public folder](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/).

For example, say you want to use the [blazeface model](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/tfjs-model/blazeface/1/default/1).  You would

1. [Download the .tar.gz model](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/tfjs-model/blazeface/1/default/1?tfjs-format=compressed) from that web page.
2. Unpack the model into your app's public directory.  So now you have the files from the .tar.gz file in a public subdir:

   ```
   %YOUR_APP%/public/blazeface_1_default_1/model.json
   %YOUR_APP%/public/blazeface_1_default_1/group1-shard1of1.bin
   ```
3. Load the model in your React app using

   ```
   tf.loadGraphModel(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + 'blazeface_1_default_1/model.json'
   ```

Comment: how do you know to use loadGraphModel or loadLayersModel for downloaded models?

Answer (score 2):

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
const tfnode = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');

async function loadModel(){
    const handler = tfnode.io.fileSystem('tfjs_model/model.json');
    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(handler);
    console.log("Model loaded")
}


loadModel();
```

This worked for me in node. Thanks to `jafaircl`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
const model = await tf.models.modelFromJSON(myModelJSON)
```

[Here it is in the tensorflow.org docs](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.13.3/#modelFromJSON)

Comment: You can't load the sharded weights (.bin files) with `modelFromJSON`

Answer (score 1):

i found a solution that it works. You can replace the url with a localhost url on xampp, for example (directory = model) http://localhost/model/model.json and after that you have to disable your browser CORS policy. For me i found a chrome extention and removed cors for my specific tab and it worked.

Thank me later!!

Answer (score 0):

Check out our documentation for loading models: https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#Models-Loading

You can use `tf.loadModel` takes a string which is a URL to your model definition which needs to get served over HTTP. This means you need to start an http-server to serve those files (it will not allow you to make a request to your filesystem because of CORS).

This package can do that for you: [npmjs.com/package/http-server](http://npmjs.com/package/http-server)

Answer (score 0):

You could use insecure chrome instance:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application>chrome.exe --disable-web-security --disable-gpu --user-data-dir=C:/Temp
```

Than you could add this script to redefine fetch function

```
async function fetch(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest
    xhr.onload = function() {
      resolve(new Response(xhr.responseText, {status: 200}))
    }
    xhr.onerror = function() {
      reject(new TypeError('Local request failed'))
    }
    xhr.open('GET', url)
    xhr.send(null)
  })
}
```

After that be shure that you use the right model loader
[my comment about loader issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/1576#issuecomment-511855196)

BUT your weights will be incorrect - as I understand there are some encoding problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to load it in server side, use `@tensorflow/tfjs-node` instead of `@tensorflow/tfjs` and update to `0.2.1` or higher version to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am using React js for loading model (for image classification and more machine learning stuff)

Tensorflow.js do not support an Api to read a previously model trained

```js
    const file= new Blob()
    file.src=modelJSON
    const files= new Blob()
    files.src=modelWeights
    console.log(files)
    const model= await tf.loadLayersModel(tf.io.browserFiles([file, files]));
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

You be able to create an APi in Express.js for servering your model (model.json and weigths.bin) if you use a web app (for a tensorflow.lite you could use a opencv.readTensorflowmodel(model.pb, weight.pbtxt)

References: [How to load tensorflow-js weights from express using tf.loadLayersModel()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62528719/how-to-load-tensorflow-js-weights-from-express-using-tf-loadlayersmodel)

```
     const classifierModel = await tf.loadLayersModel(            
            "https://rp5u7.sse.codesandbox.io/api/pokeml/classify"
        ); 
        const im = new Image()
            im.src =imagenSample//'../../../../../Models/ShapesClassification/Samples/images (2).png';
        const abc= this.preprocessImage(im);
const preds = await classifierModel.predict(abc)//.argMax(-1);
            console.log('<Response>',preds,'Principal',preds.shape[0],'DATA',preds.dataSync())
            const responde=[...preds.dataSync()]
            console.log('Maxmimo Valor',Math.max.apply(Math, responde.map(function(o) { return o; })))
            let indiceMax = this.indexOfMax(responde)
            console.log(indiceMax)
            console.log('<<<LABEL>>>',this.labelsReturn(indiceMax))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Django, you should:

1. create a directory **static** in your app and put your model there.
2. load that **static** directory to the template where you want to use your model:

   ```
   var modelPath = "{% static 'sampleModel.json' %}">
   ```

Don't forget to also load *tensorflow.js* library:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs"></script>
```

3. Now you can load your model:

   ```
   <script>model = await tf.loadGraphModel(modelPath)</script>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

## Steps to Load a Model in the Browser Using No Server:

1. **Save the Model in a `public` Folder:**  This ensures that the model is accessible from the browser.
2. **Use the following JavaScript function to load your model:**

```
// Function to load a TensorFlow.js model
async function loadModel(path) {
    return await tf.loadLayersModel(path);  // Load the model from the given path
}

const model = loadModel('yourPath'); // Replace 'yourPath' with the path to your model
```

In this snippet, `tf.loadLayersModel(path)` is called to load the model from a specified path. Remember to replace `'yourPath'` with the actual path where your model is located in the `public` folder.

With this method, your model is loaded in the browser without the need for a server.