# How to convert tensorflow.js model and weights to standard tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I want to convert a model and its respective trained weights from tensorflow.js to standard tensorflow, but cant quite figure out how to do it, the documentation of tensorflow.js dont say anything about this

I have a manifest.json and a lot of other files corresponding to the weights and bias of every layer, I want to get a .bytes file, to be used in the standard version of tensorflow

I checked the answers to other question that might be mildly related 
[How to download models and weights from tensorflow.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54066033/how-to-download-models-and-weights-from-tensorflow-js)
(I asked that question) which was only partially answered, answer that doesnt give any hints regarding this one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download models and weights from tensorflow.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54066033/how-to-download-models-and-weights-from-tensorflow-js)

Comment: I'm the same person that posted that question, and this part wasnt answered, if you have the answer to this specific question pls share

Answer (score 6):

Tensorflow.js converter can convert the tfjs model into Keras HDF5 format with following params:

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tfjs_layers_model --output_format=keras path/to/tfjs_files path/to/save_keras_hdf5
```

You can take a look [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-converter) for installing the converting.
Once the model is converted to Keras HDF5 you can convert it the TensorFlow SavedModel format. So, this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45466020/how-to-export-keras-h5-to-tensorflow-pb/45466355) might be helpful.

**Note:** This works for a model in the 'tfjs layers model' format, but not the `tfjs graph model` format.