# Load object recognition model created in Colab in a Javascript web page

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js, object-recognition

I made my object recognition model by following this example:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification

I create this model using Colab, and now I have, from Colab, a model in **.py** and **.ipynb**

Using this istruction I save my model in **.h5**:

`model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['binary_accuracy'])`

`model.save('./modelname.h5')`

Now, I can try to save this model in another format, I use this code and save it in **.json** and with **group1-shard°of°.bin** files:

`!pip install tensorflowjs` 

`!mkdir model`

`!tensorflowjs_converter --input_format keras modelname.h5 model/`

`!zip -r modelname.zip model`

Now my goal is to be able to load this model into my webapp, in Javascript, and use it to recognize images

The problem is being able to load the model

Any solution?

**UPDATE**
I'm using a screenshot of my page view as an image to recognize
This is my fundamental part of the code:

```
async function LoadModel() {
    Model = await tf.loadLayersModel('http://localhost/..../model.json'); //caricamento mio modello
    console.log('conferma caricamento modello ' + Model);
try {
    maxPredictions = Model.getTotalClasses();
    console.log("durante");
}
catch (e){}
if (Model) {
    //controllo caricamento modello
    console.log(Model);
}
console.log("dopo e modello " + Model);
}
```

Then

```
OriginImage.onload = function (event) {
try { 
document.createEvent("TouchEvent"); 
var width = document.body.clientWidth;
}
catch(e) { 
var width = ResizeImageWidth;
} 
if (OriginImage.height<OriginImage.width) {
    var height = width*OriginImage.height/OriginImage.width; 
    }
else {
    var height = width;
    width = height*OriginImage.width/OriginImage.height; 
    }
ResizeImage.width = width;
ResizeImage.height = height;  
ResizeImage.src = OriginImage.src;
}
```

This is resize

```
ResizeImage.onload = function (event) {
if (Model) recognizeImage(ResizeImage);
}
```

And this is recognizeImage

```
async function recognizeImage(Image) {
var cont;
var data = "";
var maxClassName = "";
var maxProbability = "";
const prediction = await Model.predict(Image);
for (let i = 0; i < maxPredictions; i++) {
    if (i==0) {
        maxClassName = prediction[i].className;
        maxProbability = prediction[i].probability;
    }
    else if (prediction[i].probability>maxProbability) {
        maxClassName = prediction[i].className;
        maxProbability = prediction[i].probability;
    }
}
if(maxProbability > 0.90 ) {
        console.log(maxProbability + '  than' + maxClassName);
    return;
} 
else {
    console.log(maxProbability + maxClassName + "Nothing" );
    }
}
```

Comment: What issue do you have in loading the model ?

Comment: I can't load the model from the start, I can't find a method or a procedure that loads me the model correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can load it using

```
tf.loadLayersModel(modelUrl)
```

On node, the file can be accessed directly. The browser however does not have access to the file system; so the model.json needs to be served by a server first. It has been discussed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53639919/load-tensorflow-js-model-from-local-file-system-in-javascript/53712229#53712229)

Comment: I recived this error

`Error: Error when checking model : the Array of Tensors that you are passing to your model is not the size the the model expected. Expected to see 1 Tensor(s), but instead got 0 Tensors(s).
    at new e (tf.min.js:2)
    at Bm (tf.min.js:2)
    at e.predict (tf.min.js:2)
    at e.predict (tf.min.js:2)
    at recognizeImage (index.js:528)
    at HTMLImageElement.ResizeImage.onload (index.js:519)`

Comment: Could you please update your question with the js code that throws the error ?

Comment: I don't know if it's my mistake
More than anything else I'm applying a screen of the page view as an image to recognize,I immediately load the parts of code involved

Answer (score 0):

I am using React js for loading model (image classification and more machine learning stuff)

Tensorflow.js do not support an Api to read a previously model trained

```js
    const file= new Blob()
    file.src=modelJSON
    const files= new Blob()
    files.src=modelWeights
    console.log(files)
    const model= await tf.loadLayersModel(tf.io.browserFiles([file, files]));
```

[image]

You be able to create an APi in Express.js for servering your model (model.json and weigths.bin) if you use a web app (for a tensorflow.lite you could use a opencv.readTensorflowmodel(model.pb, weight.pbtxt)

References: [How to load tensorflow-js weights from express using tf.loadLayersModel()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62528719/how-to-load-tensorflow-js-weights-from-express-using-tf-loadlayersmodel)

```
     const classifierModel = await tf.loadLayersModel(            
            "https://rp5u7.sse.codesandbox.io/api/pokeml/classify"
        ); 
        const im = new Image()
            im.src =imagenSample//'../../../../../Models/ShapesClassification/Samples/images (2).png';
        const abc= this.preprocessImage(im);
const preds = await classifierModel.predict(abc)//.argMax(-1);
            console.log('<Response>',preds,'Principal',preds.shape[0],'DATA',preds.dataSync())
            const responde=[...preds.dataSync()]
            console.log('Maxmimo Valor',Math.max.apply(Math, responde.map(function(o) { return o; })))
            let indiceMax = this.indexOfMax(responde)
            console.log(indiceMax)
            console.log('<<<LABEL>>>',this.labelsReturn(indiceMax))
```

Comment: Is this an answer to the above question? I can't see connection, and your image seem to indicate you are asking

Comment: Hi after many springs I code a Express.js server (references:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62528719/how-to-load-tensorflow-js-weights-from-express-using-tf-loadlayersmodel). Now my React.js web app is using an axios that made a post petition to my tensorflow.js model hosted in express.