# Load a Tensorflow.js model locally

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, tensorflow

Currently I am trying to load a json model that I've converted from tensorflow into my tensorflow function.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@2.0.0/dist/tf.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    //!pip install tensorflowjs;
    // * as tf from '@tensorlowjs/tfjs';
    async function tensorFlow(){
    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('AI-Model/model.json');

}

tensorFlow()

</script>
```

[Directory of my GitHub Repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4Mee.png)

However, when I try to add the json file I get the error that loadLayersModel() expects a http request. Is there a way to load in my model from the repository? If not how do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow.js can't access local files directly (unless you're doing it in Node.js). Take a look at some of [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53639919/load-tensorflow-js-model-from-local-file-system-in-javascript).

Looking at the [Tensorflow.js API](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#loadLayersModel), your options appear to be either:

1. Load the model from an HTTP server
2. Load the model from user-selected files from [HTML file input
   elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file).

Answer (score -1):

Replace this line `const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('AI-Model/model.json');` by `const model = await tf.loadGraphModel('http:AI-Model/model.json');`

Comment: Requesting you to write in English to attract more audience